# When using gradle does the version and sdk information need to be duplicated in the android manifest?

Tags: android, gradle

The android developer guide ([Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)) specifies that the manifest should contain version number info, as well as minimum and target sdk versions. Like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.package.name"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.1">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

However in a gradle build the build.gradle file for the app contains all of this information ([Gradle build system user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries)), like so:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.0"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    } 
}
```

**Is it necessary to include this information in the android manifest as well as the gradle file, or will it be populated correctly by the gradle build system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove these from the Manifest.xml and have them just in the build.gradle.

I've been doing this on several of my projects for a while now with no down side.